# Допустимы ли на мете вопросы о спец. предложениях от IT компаний для пользователей SO?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, мета

Неоднозначное мнение сложилось у людей после этого вопроса: [Есть ли бесплатные лицензии IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate для активных участников Stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7989/15479)

И хотелось бы услышать обоснованное и аргументированное мнение участников на этот счёт в виде ответов. Я лично не исключаю возможность создания одного каноничного вопроса, где будет список таких компаний с их предложениями.

Такие вопросы - это онтопик для меты или нет?

Comment: этот вопрос задан по следам обсуждения в чате, приведу [ссылку](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46934322#46934322) на начало дискуссии.

Comment: Хорошая идея - создать один вопрос, где будет собрана вся информация о подобных *промо-акциях* компаний. Главное - не забывать актуализировать данную информацию, в соответствии с реалиями жизни.

Comment: если подобное и предоставляется(лицензия, акция и т.п.), то это должно быть в новостях ru.so или спец разделе на той же странице помощи. Или же можно создать страницу(вопрос) как по книгам. Отдельные вопросы приведут к q/a а-ля "есть?" - "да/нет"

Comment: Кстати, если бы SO заключила договор на поставку лицензий каких-либо программ участнику, у которого например больше 5к рейтинга, то это был бы еще 1 хороший стимул отвечать на вопросы, мне кажется.

Answer (score 9):

> TL; DR Моё мнение — это вполне нормальный вопрос на мете, его не стоит закрывать или пытаться натянуть на глобус "перепишем на любую компанию".

Нет никаких оснований закрывать вопрос: [На Мете приветствуются любые вопросы каким-либо образом касающиеся Stack Overflow на русском.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Для меня странен довод (приводившийся в обсуждении в чате) "выдаст ли ашан скидку участнику So" — есть разница между Ашаном (не ИТ-компания) и между JB (ИТ-компания). То есть вопрос имеет связь с онтопиком не только через "участник So", но и тематичностью компании.

Также я не понимаю отсылку к "на основном сайте за вопросы по конкретному продукту закрывают". Я такое видел когда находят баг (советуют багтрекер), когда просят новую фичу (логично, что фичереквесты надо в компанию), но когда спрашивают конкретный вопрос "вот вижуал студия как в ней сделать то-то" — то такие вопросы очевидно тематические и не закрывают.

Мог бы понять, если бы вопрос звучал как фичереквест ("хочу, чтобы JB сделали"), но ведь он звучит как "есть ли у JB" - ведь автор не знает, может уже есть, просто он не слышал.

Я уверен, что если будут появляться вопросы про скидки в ашане — то его действительно заминусуют и закроют.

Но сейчас вопрос про конкретную компанию — пусть таковым и останется, потому что в комментариях двое людей написали конкретику вида "я спрашивал у разрабов этой компании, они порекомендовали то-то" и переписывание вопроса под нож убьёт эту специфику.

Мне нужно как-то пояснять, что я лично не имею материального интереса в этом вопросе? Моя компания оплачивает лицензии на visual studio, resharper, PHP Storm и лично мне до фени наличие/отсутствие такой фичи — но я действительно уверен, что мир станет немного лучше, если у молодёжи будет легальный доступ к хорошим инструментам.

А вопросы про любую другую айтишную компанию пусть задают, я не хочу гадать, что захочет сделать эта конкретная компания. И дело даже не в размере компании. Могу напомнить, что на последней московской встрече ruso один из участников бесплатно раздал доступ к продукции своей компании — в дополнение к маечкам-блокнотикам Николаса. То есть для любой компании это может быть потенциально выгодно.

> я допускаю существование **одного** такого вопроса в виде канонического со списком предложений от компаний.
>   Но я против вопросов по **каждой** компании.

Не могу сказать, что однозначно против или за такого предложения.

Наверное, стоило всё же подождать пока таких вопросов появится несколько десятков — и тогда написать один сводный вопрос (типа как мы закрываем на дублем на канонический или составляем список книг по теме).

Ну или так: даже не дожидаясь предложений от компаний создать канонический ответ "вот эти компании предоставляют бесплатные ништяки участникам so", но ведь и таких вроде нет ни одной для составления мегасписка.

Понимаете просто в чём мой пойнт? В том что я за свободу и не приемлю попытки оградить её. Свобода задать вопрос — это один из краеугольных столпов stackoverflow и должны быть какие-то очень серьёзные обоснования чтобы эту свободу ограничивать. Вам жалко место на диске под ещё один вопрос? Нет. Вам кажется, что подобных вопросов станут задавать массово? Тоже нет, разве кто-нибудь нарочно наштампует. Этот вопрос нетематичен? Нет, вполне тематичен — и потенциально причиняет добро неограниченному числу участников. Тогда в чём беда, что заставляет вас ограничивать свободу создания вопросов?

Если появится какой-то аргументированный повод — я возможно передумаю и поменяю свою точку зрения, а пока - мне кажется нет смысла играть в игру "ща как запрещу!"

Comment: когда цитируете, то добавьте прямые ссылки, пожалуйста.

Comment: Разве есть компании, предоставляющие какие-либо льготу участникам SO?   
"Один из участников бесплатно раздал доступ к продукции своей компании" - а что за компания?

Answer (score 2):

Прочитал обсуждение и решил дать свое видение ситуации.

### Реклама или...?

Знаете, мне кажется, что подобные вопросы - это почти что реклама продукта. А реклама, я полагаю, должна быть согласованной с администрацией и не попадать в основные вопросы (т.е. быть оперативно перемещена/удалена в зависимости от договоренности администрации SO с представителями компании. На полноценный вопрос это не тянет - ибо можно любую компанию "подставить" на место JB.

В ответе участника **A K** выше была указано, цитата:

> Мог бы понять, если бы вопрос звучал как фичереквест ("хочу, чтобы JB сделали"), но ведь он звучит как "есть ли у JB" - ведь автор не знает, может уже есть, просто он не слышал.

Тогда, может быть, автору подобного вопроса лучше напрямую обратиться к представителям JB? Кто лучше них знает ответ?

> Могу напомнить, что на последней московской встрече ruso один из участников бесплатно раздал доступ к продукции своей компании — в дополнение к маечкам-блокнотикам Николаса. То есть для любой компании это может быть потенциально выгодно

Верно, компании могут раздавать участникам на неформальных встречах все, что угодно. Но ведь мы ведем речь о SO - компании, которая имеет определенные затраты. Так почему же не попытаться монетизировать подобные вопросы, чтобы от них был определенный полезный коэффициент, если *любой компании выгодно рекламировать себя?* (а уж тем более на SO).
Пока же, мне не видно выгоды для остальных участников сообщества (допускаю, что никто финансовую отчетность мне не предоставит). Не все используют продукты JB. Для тех, кому это критично - есть сайт компании, там можно прочитать последние новости о продукте(-ах) *из первых рук*.

### Возможное решение

Быть может, лучший вариант - размещение подобного контента в специальной секции сайта (метку какую-нибудь смастерить под это дело).
На крайний случай можно создать спец-аккаунт для представителей компании (любой, которая захочет здесь быть) и позволить им в *специальной теме* писать различные предложения, акции и т.д. На текущий момент, такие вопросы от *рядовых* пользователей выглядят как вопросы на широкую тему, а, следовательно, подлежат закрытию/удалению.

### Вывод

В приведенном для обсуждения вопросе не содержится и намека на связь между компанией JB и SO. Потому что если аббревиатура SO дает "зеленый свет" любому вопросу, то аналогия с магазином (как приведено в чате участником **Suvitruf**) выглядит весьма уместной.

В заключение своего ответа я хочу подчеркнуть ту мысль, которую я попытался выразить:
*Если человека интересует продукт А компании Б, то человек должен осведомляться о продукте А на сайте компании Б. И там же задавать все интересующие его вопросы.*

Comment: У меня открывается. У вас 404 там?

Comment: К сожалению, именно так.

Comment: А если по ссылке из блока справа? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7989/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b8-intellij-idea-ultimate-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-stack?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Suvitruf, какой же я невнимательный. Этот вопрос (по ссылке, которую Вы дали) я прочитал. Открывается отлично. Я хотел оригинал вопроса посмотреть. По ссылке в Вашем комментарии есть текст, цитата: Перенесён с ru.stackoverflow.com 27 сен в 2:11. И в этом тексте содержится ссылка на этот адрес: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/886023/revisions. При переходе на него он выдает 404. Перенесли и удалили, видимо. Я неверно выразился в своем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

В том виде, в котором появился вопрос о «халяве» для участников SO, он заслуживает закрытия (и я голосовал за это) как оффтопичный. Объясняю почему. Хотя в вопросе и есть притянутое за уши упоминание SO, чтобы на него ответить нужно быть знатоком продуктов и промо-акций совсем другой компании (JB), а не SO. Возможно, такой человек с аккаунтом SO даже найдётся, в чём я лично очень сомневаюсь. А если нет, то может быть кто-то другой воспользуется гугло-поиском по сайту JB и попытается найти ответ из короткого слова «нет». Но зачем нужен такой ответ на Мете SO? Такой ответ не нужен, равно как и вопрос, его порождающий. Вот если бы вопрос звучал как анонс вида «JB даёт бесплатные лицензии активным участникам SO» с подробным описанием, что подразумевается под всем этим от настоящего сотрудника JB. Такой вопрос вполне мог бы присутствовать на Мете, по моему скромному мнению. Хотя и здесь есть нюансы, вытекающие из цитаты, упомянутой в смежном ответе:

> [На Мете приветствуются любые вопросы каким-либо образом касающиеся Stack Overflow на русском.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Как говорил дедушка Ленин: «не стоит верить каждой цитате в интернете». И этот случай не исключение. Вы же все знаете, что ruSO это лишь калька с анлоязычного Stack Overflow? И ключевые концепции использования сайта на ruSO такие же как на enSO. Просто посмотрим на тот же абзац в [оригинале](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), для этого достаточно просто убрать `ru.` из адресной строки. Но что мы там видим? А там мы, собственно, ничего подобного и не видим. Приведу для сравнения оба варианта здесь в виде картинок:

> [image: ruso]

> [image: enSO]

Таким образом приписка, на которую ссылаются сторонники разрешения подобных вопросов на Мете просто лишь очередной «локализаторский произвол» (инициатива переводчика).

И, конечно же, не стоит думать, что тем, кто против присутствия подобных вопросов на Мете жалко какого-то там места на каком-то там сервере, за который платят какие-то там неизвестные нам люди. Просто мы за чистоту как ruSO, так и её Меты, без расширения онтопика типа пространных «диалогов-о-работе», которыми тут можно вообще всё было бы завалить при желании.